# php call to file_get_contents() terminates script

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I have written a small PHP script that I am running from the command line locally in VS-Code (no browser). The script connects to a URL using `file_get_contents()` up to 4,000 times to download different JSON files.

After a period of time the call is made to `file_get_contents()`, but doesn't return and the script terminates. I have put an `echo` statement before and after the `file_get_contents()` call to try and diagnose the problem.

I thought at first it was a timeout issue, but this is not the case as I can make between 200 and 1,500 successful calls ranging from 30 to 150 seconds. It looks as if the connection is being dropped/rejected/terminated by the other end, but the problem I have is that I am unable to prevent my script from terminating. I have looked in the C:\wamp64\logs folder, but nothing is being logged.

Is there any way of determining what is causing the issue, and more importantly, prevent my script from terminating, so that it can continue.
I have not created/modified any header information for the call to `file_get_contents()`.

```
foreach ($urls as $url) {
echo "URL: $url\n";
echo "Get file data\n";
$json = file_get_contents($url);
echo "Got file data\n";
}
```

Sample output...
Get file data

[Done] exited with code=null in 325.239 seconds

Comment: If you need a solution or a suggestion then post the code. If you want only to chat then you are on the wrong website. Read about [ask] a good question.

Comment: Can you drop some code in and we can attempt to answer at least the question of the terminating script part.  That way you will be halfway there...

Comment: I have updated with a code sample.

Comment: How about you remove the error silencing operator `@` and see what errors are thrown...

Comment: Not a good day :-( Sorry, the '@' character shouldn't have been there. I saw someone else suggest it so I just added it out of frustration. I'll remove it from the code sample.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I have finally got to the bottom of the problem. The problem was related to how it was being run in VS Code. By adding the following setting (File | Preference | Settings) to run code in the integrated terminal and not the output window, it now works :-)

```
{
    "code-runner.runInTerminal": true
}
```